SIGABRT: Cannot form weak reference to instance of class UIWindow
I'm testing my app via TestFlight at the minute. Out of about 10,000 sessions, I have 6 crashes reported in sentry with the above title, when the app is backgrounded. Crash reports from TestFlight offer very little to go on:

Sentry offers a little bit more info, with the title/description of:
SIGABRT
Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x1055809f0) of class UIWindow. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation. > objc[6171]: Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x1055809f0) of class UIWindow. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.
And breadcrumbs showing it happened after the app was backgrounded:

The only thing that I do consistently with the window when backgrounding is cover the screen with another window to protect users private info (financial data)
Inside SceneDelegate's sceneDidEnterBackground I run this
func showPrivacyProtectionWindow() {
    guard let windowScene = self.window?.windowScene else {
        return
    }
        
    privacyProtectionWindowVisible = true
    privacyProtectionWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    privacyProtectionWindow?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() ?? UIViewController()
    privacyProtectionWindow?.windowLevel = .alert + 1
    privacyProtectionWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}

This covers the screen in a company logo, and upon returning to the app, forces the user to enter a passcode. Once done, it's removed via:
func hidePrivacyProtectionWindow() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
        self?.privacyProtectionWindow?.alpha = 0
            
    } completion: { [weak self] finish in
        self?.privacyProtectionWindow = nil
        self?.privacyProtectionWindowVisible = false
        self?.dismissedPrivacyProtectionWindow = true
    }
}

This is the only thing I can think of that might be causing the issue. But it works 99.9999% of the time and I can't reproduce the issue. What might be causing this and how to address it?

Whoever comes across this message, we had a similar problem in our project. The reason was that we were storing UIWindow inside UIViewController object and rootViewController of that UIWindow was self (UIViewController object). So, before removing references to that UIWindow so that ARC could deallocate this object, we needed to do rootViewController = nil and the crash was gone.
